# InvalidArgumentException: Invalid translation language (fr) specified

Tags: theming, i18n-l10n

I'm currently trying to translate my twig template to the current language and at this moment I'm getting the following error

> InvalidArgumentException: Invalid translation language (fr) specified.
>   in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->getTranslation() (line 872 of
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iom/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityBase.php).

Here is a snippet of code that I'm currently working on

```
// Page-level pre-processing
function iom_preprocess_page(&$variables) {   

    $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage();
    $variables['lang_code'] = $language->getId();
}
```

---

```
{% if (language.getId() == 'fr')  %}

    <li class="tab">{{ tab_label.entity.field_tab_title.entity.translation('fr').label }}</li>

{% else %}

    <li class="tab">{{ tab_label.entity.field_tab_title.entity.label }}</li>

{% endif %}
```

---

Somehow this part right here is what seems to be causing the error even though the language is currently correct

```
<li class="tab">{{ tab_label.entity.field_tab_title.entity.translation('fr').label }}</li>
```

Comment: should check on `lang_code` not `language.getId()`  something like `{% if tab_label.entity.hastranslation(lang_code) %}  {{ tab_label.entity.translation(lang_code).field_tab_title.entity.label }}`

Comment: Why you need to do this, normally the correct language is selected and rendered by the system if it's exist a translation...

Answer (score 2):

Should check on `lang_code` the variable you already passed from preprocess, not `language.getId()` try something like that:

```
{% if lang_code == 'fr' and tab_label.entity.hastranslation(lang_code) %}
  <li class="tab">{{ tab_label.entity.translation(lang_code).field_tab_title.entity.label }}</li>
{% else %}
  <li class="tab">{{ tab_label.entity.field_tab_title.entity.label }}</li>
{% endif %}
```